# Variable undefined error when variable is used inside lookup dig filter while looping through group of hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a jinja2 template to loop through a group and lookup the IPs for each host in the group.  When I use the variable defined in the loop inside the lookup dig filter I get an error that the variable is undefined.

```
template.j2 
{% for node in groups['group1'] %}
  IP: {{ lookup('dig', '{{ node }}') }}
{% endfor %}
```

the lookup dig filter works fine when I put an individual FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
{% for node in groups['group1'] %}
  IP: {{ lookup('dig', node) }}
{% endfor %}
```